# Loading data from Database + Network (Room + Retrofit + RxJava2)

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2, android-room

I have a sample API request which returns a list of user's watchlist. I want to achieve the following **flow when the user loads the watchlist screen**:

1. Load the data from DB cache immediately.(`cacheWatchList`)
2. Initiate the RetroFit network call in the background.

   i. `onSuccess` return `apiWatchList`
    ii. `onError` return `cacheWatchList`
3. Diff `cacheWatchList` vs `apiWatchList`

   i. Same -> all is well since data is already displayed to the user do nothing.

   ii. Differs -> Save `apiWatchList` to a local store and send the `apiWatchList` to the downstream.

**What I have done so far?**

**Watchlist.kt**

```
data class Watchlist(
  val items: List<Repository> = emptyList()
)
```

**LocalStore.kt** (Android room)

```
  fun saveUserWatchlist(repositories: List<Repository>): Completable {    
    return Completable.fromCallable {      
      watchlistDao.saveAllUserWatchlist(*repositories.toTypedArray())
    }
  }
```

**RemoteStore.kt** (Retrofit api call)

```
  fun getWatchlist(userId: UUID): Single<Watchlist?> {
    return api.getWatchlist(userId)
  }
```

**DataManager.kt**

```
  fun getWatchlist(userId: UUID): Flowable<List<Repository>?> {
    val localSource: Single<List<Repository>?> =
      localStore.getUserWatchlist()
        .subscribeOn(scheduler.computation)

    val remoteSource: Single<List<Repository>> = remoteStore.getWatchlist(userId)
      .map(Watchlist::items)
      .doOnSuccess { items: List<Repository> ->
        localStore.saveUserWatchlist(items)
          .subscribeOn(scheduler.io)
          .subscribe()
      }
      .onErrorResumeNext { throwable ->
        if (throwable is IOException) {
          return@onErrorResumeNext localStore.getUserWatchlist()
        }
        return@onErrorResumeNext Single.error(throwable)
      }
      .subscribeOn(scheduler.io)

    return Single.concat(localSource, remoteSource)
  }
```

The problem with the above flow is, it calls `onNext` **twice** for each stream source to the downstream(presenter) even though both the data are same.

I can do the data diff logic in the presenter and update accordingly but I want the `DataManager` class to handle the logic for me(CleanArchitecture, SOC).

**My Questions?**

1. What's the best possible way to implement the above logic?
2. Am I leaking the inner subscriptions in DataManager (see: `doOnSuccess` code) ?. I'm disposing of the outer subscription when the presenter is destroyed.

Comment: tried google's [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) library?

Comment: @pskink By extending the default adapter to `PagedListAdapter` we can solve the issue. But again `PagedListAdapter` results change in the presentation layer, I want the data layer to handle the data changes.

Comment: what do you mean? cannot you invalidate() your `DataSource`?

Comment: @pskink Too brief, I don't want to write some logic in presentation(UI) layer, changing the adapter implementation or writing DiffUtils callback mechanism. I want to make presenter as dumb as possible, want Data layer to take care of sending the right data at right time.

Comment: your presenter will only have to create `LivePagedListProvider` and all the logic you will implement in your custom `DataSource`

Comment: @pskink I hadn't tried paging library yet just read about it, will try implementing the same using paging library and update here.  I expected a reactive solution which combines multiple/chain of RxJava2 operators to resolve the issue, let's see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159305/discussion-between-blizzard-and-pskink).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
fun getWatchlist(userId: UUID): Observable<List<Repository>?> {
val remoteSource: Single<List<Repository>> = 
remoteStore.getWatchlist(userId)
        .map(Watchlist::items)
        .subscribeOn(scheduler.io)

return localStore.getUserWatchlist()
        .flatMapObservable { listFromLocal: List<Repository> ->
            remoteSource
                    .observeOn(scheduler.computation)
                    .toObservable()
                    .filter { apiWatchList: List<Repository> ->
                        apiWatchList != listFromLocal
                    }
                    .flatMapSingle { apiWatchList ->
                        localSource.saveUserWatchlist(apiWatchList)
                                .andThen(Single.just(apiWatchList))
                    }
                    .startWith(listFromLocal)
        }
}
```

Explanation step by step:

1. Load data from localStore
2. Use flatMapObservable to subscribe to remoteSource each time the localStore emits data.
3. As there are more than one emission from inner observable(initial data from local and new data in case of updated data from the remoteSource) transform Single to Observable.
4. Compare data from remoteSource with data from the localStore and proceed data only in case if newData != localData.
5. For each emission after the filter initiate the localSource to save data and on a completion of this operation proceed saved data as Single.
6. As requested, at the beginning of remote request data from localStore should be proceeded and it is simply done be adding startWith at the end of the operators chain.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. Please add little bit textual explanation for the return part of your code, beneficial to the entire community. I'll then mark it as the answer.